# Finite generation of ring of automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, division-ring

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Frac}{Frac}$
Hello everybody.
My question is about **Proposition $6.2.7.$** in the book *"Basic Structures of Function Field Arithmetic"* by David Goss.

Given a field $L$ with an $\sigma$ automorphism of infinite order, one can consider the ring $L\{\sigma\}$
that consists of all polynomial-like expressions $\sum_{n=0}^N a_n \cdot \sigma^n$ with multiplication given by $(a\cdot \sigma )\cdot (b \cdot \sigma):=a\cdot \sigma(b) \sigma^2$ etc.

This ring is graded by the degree $\deg(\sum_{n=0}^N a_n\cdot \sigma^n):=N,a_N\not =0$.

Let $R$ be a commutative subring of $L\{\sigma\}$.

The proposition is about proving that $R$ and $\mathscr{R}:=\bigoplus_{d=0}^\infty R_d$ are finitely generated $R_0$-algebras where $R_d:=\{f\in R\mid \deg(f)\leq d\}$.

In the proof it is claimed, that $\Frac(R)$ ($L\{\sigma\}$ is a domain) contains an element $\alpha$ of order $t:=\gcd(\deg(r)\mid r\in R)$.

**I don't see how to prove this.**

My attempt is to consider $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\in \Frac(R)$ of degrees $\deg(\alpha)=a t$ and $\deg(\beta)=b t$.
So we need to find $\alpha,\beta\in R$ such that $a-b=1$.
Actually it would be enough to find $\alpha,\beta$
 such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$, but I don't see how to show this either. Of course, the plain definition of $t$ does not imply the existence of an element in $R$ of degree $t$, but that such an element exists in the quotient field sound plausible, so I belive the statement of the proof must be correct.

The sequel of the proof is also a bit incomprehensive for me, but this is another topic.

I help somebody who can figure out the answer is willing to explain it tome.
Thank You for Your effort!

greetings.